# android: xml parsing output in tableview

Tags: java, android, xml

i am newbie to android.
i have searched code and done xml parsing but its in listview...
i need that it should be in tableview
please help me out...
my code is as follows:

```
class MyXMLHandler

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

Boolean currentElement = false;
String currentValue = null;
public static SitesList sitesList = null;

public static SitesList getSitesList() {
    return sitesList;
}

public static void setSitesList(SitesList sitesList) {
    MyXMLHandler.sitesList = sitesList;
}

/** Called when tag starts ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
 * -- <name> )*/
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currentElement = true;

    if (localName.equals("maintag"))
    {
        /** Start */
        sitesList = new SitesList();
    } else if (localName.equals("website")) {
        /** Get attribute value */
       // String attr = attributes.getValue("category");
       // sitesList.setCategory(attr);
    }

    }

    /** Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
 * -- </name> )*/
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

    currentElement = false;

    /** set value */
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
            sitesList.setName(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("website"))
            sitesList.setWebsite(currentValue);

    }

/** Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
     * -- to get AndroidPeople Character ) */
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentElement = false;
        }

    }
```

}

Second class SitesList

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/** Contains getter and setter method for variables  */
public class SitesList {

    /** Variables */
    private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> website = new ArrayList<String>();
  //  private ArrayList<String> category = new ArrayList<String>();

    /** In Setter method default it will return arraylist
     *  change that to add  */

    public ArrayList<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.add(name);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website.add(website);
    }

  /**public ArrayList<String> getCategory() {
        return category;
   }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category.add(category);
   }**/
```

}

and third class is MyParsingExample

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class XMLParsingExample extends Activity {

/** Create Object For SiteList Class */
SitesList sitesList = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** Create a new layout to display the view */
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(1);

    /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
    TextView name[];
    TextView website[];
    //TextView category[];

    try {

        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://ipaddress/test/file.xml");

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

    /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
    sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

    /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
    name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
    website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
   //category = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

    /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
    for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
        name[i] = new TextView(this);
        name[i].setText("Name = "+sitesList.getName().get(i));
        website[i] = new TextView(this);
        website[i].setText("Website = "+sitesList.getWebsite().get(i));
        /**category[i] = new TextView(this);
        category[i].setText("Website Category = "+sitesList.getCategory().get(i));**/

        layout.addView(name[i]);
        layout.addView(website[i]);
        //layout.addView(category[i]);
    }

    /** Set the layout view to display */
    setContentView(layout);

}
```

and xml file is

```
<maintag>
<!-- Table item -->
<item>
  <name>sam</name>
  <website>sam</website>
</item>
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't get your point. Could you please edit the first paragraph of your question to tell us in detail: 1.) What you're trying to do 2.) What is the result 3.) What you expect the result to be that would help to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay *Uff* Chaaanleeenge Accepted

I think i can guess what you want to do. First of all, basicly your code does the following:

- Parsing your XML File and putting the results into SitesList
- Creating all the layout stuff programaticly
- For every Item which has been parsed it generates a new TextView

So there is no ListView in there.

You now want to put the parsed values into a TableView. So just let me say, that how you build up your code for generating the layout isn't the best to keep your Presentation Stuff away from your code. Android is very well designed for that purpose. You should have a closer look to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html especcially to the layout resources. You can do your layout stuff in xml files.

But back to your current problem. To Show your stuff in a table you have to edit your `MyParsingExample` activity.

(I can't test the code at the moment but it should work as follows:)

```
/** Create a new layout to display the view */
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(1);
```

At this point you should use a `TableLayout` like this for example:

```
/** Create a new layout to display the view */
TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(this);
```

So the tableLayout is just another way to *layout* other components.

Now you need to have a look at this part:

```
/** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
//category = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

/** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
    name[i] = new TextView(this);
    name[i].setText("Name = "+sitesList.getName().get(i));
    website[i] = new TextView(this);
    website[i].setText("Website = "+sitesList.getWebsite().get(i));
    /**category[i] = new TextView(this);
    category[i].setText("Website Category = "+sitesList.getCategory().get(i));**/

    layout.addView(name[i]);
    layout.addView(website[i]);
    //layout.addView(category[i]);
}
```

Thats the point where the Textviews has been generated. You need to substitude  it by some code which generates Rows into the the tableview. As i said i cannot test the code at the moment. But i am reffering to:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html
and
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html

For example like this:

```
/** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
//category = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

/** Add rows for every entry and add it to layout */
for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
    //we can leave that part as it is
    name[i] = new TextView(this);
    name[i].setText("Name = "+sitesList.getName().get(i));

    website[i] = new TextView(this);
    website[i].setText("Website = "+sitesList.getWebsite().get(i));

    //now we create a new row
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

    //we add the textviews to the row
    row.addView(name[i]);
    row.addView(website[i]);

    //and we add the row to the tablelayout
    layout.addView(row);
}
```

I really hope that helps you to go on with that. I in general recommend to have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html this is the best page to start learning android programming.

Comment: your welcome. If this answer solved your problem it would be nice if you accept it. thx