# parse xml with tag

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm following this example to parse a xml [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180360/android-xml-parsing-output-in-tableview) but when I try to parse xml I get error. 
The Xml is Reg Variacion="20" />

I need show TextView[]; 20, 20, 20

This is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SitesList sitesList = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);


        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */

        TextView registro[];
        TextView variacion[];

        try {

            /** Handling XML */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
            URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://www.bovalpo.com/cgi-local/xml_bcv.pl?URL=75");


            /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
            MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
            }


        /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
        sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;


        /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
        registro = new TextView[sitesList.getRegistro().size()];
        variacion = new TextView[sitesList.getVariacion().size()];


        /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
        for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getRegistro().size(); i++) {

            registro[i] = new TextView(this);
            registro[i].setText(sitesList.getRegistro().get(i));
            variacion[i] = new TextView(this);
            variacion[i].setText(sitesList.getVariacion().get(i));


            layout.addView(registro[i]);
            //layout.addView(category[i]);
        }

        /** Set the layout view to display */
        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

**MyXMLHandler.java**

```
DefaultHandler {
    @Override public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currentElement = true;
    if (localName.equals("root"))
    {
        /** Start */
        sitesList = new SitesList();

    } else if (localName.equals("registro")) {

        String attr = attributes.getValue("Variacion");
        String var = String.valueOf(attr);
        sitesList.setVariacion(var);
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

    currentElement = false;

    /** set value */
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("registro"))
            sitesList.setRegistro(currentValue);

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentElement = false;
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: *"when I try to parse xml I get error"* is rather vague, can you be more specific? What does the stacktrace in LogCat say? For starters I can tell you that `localName.equals("registro")` will never be true, as the returned xml shows `Registro` (capitalized 'R').

Comment: When you do something and get an error, tell us what the error is. You might not understand the error message, but there's a very good chance that we do.

Comment: I solved the problem, was parse error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the **DOM PARSER** ( Document Object Model )

**See this link:**

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html

Comment: I tried use DOM PARSER but I was asked parser do with this method because it is easier to add color

Comment: Then try Push Parse the best of both the worlds